# How to display moment.js time on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, momentjs

I'm using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) and I put the following script on my webpage:

```
<script>
    var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
    $('time').append(newYork);
</script>
```

and the html code:

```
<div id="time">
    some text
</div>
```

I would like to display the current time in new york, but all I see is `some text`. How can I put the time in that div? Thanks!

Comment: jQuery's selector for ID is `#id`, not `id`. You should use `$('#time')`.

Answer (score 1):

`$('time')` should actually be `$('#time')`

Answer (score 0):

assuming `var newYork` is correct try:

```
var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
$('#time').append(newYork);
```

if you want to replace inner html do this:

```
$('#time').html(newYork);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did so, of course I forgot `#`, however I still see only `some text` instead of the date in New York appent to it, I don't know where might be the problem.. I want to display this time as soon as the webpage loads, so I surrounded it with `jQuery(document).ready(function () {` but that didn't help and the `some text` is still visible,,

Comment: Hey, thanks, that works, I can append text to the empty div, but so far only when `var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");` is commented out, I guess there's sth wrong with this declaration

Comment: Judging from your comments, I have a hunch that you might have forgotten to include the requisite [timezone.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) file